# SQL Select Distinct still showing duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm have the following query using the `DISTINCT` clause but the results are still showing duplicate ID's:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    rl.countryid, rl.resellerid, c.countryname, c.iso2, r.resellerid 
FROM reseller_locator rl 
INNER JOIN countries c 
    ON rl.countryid = c.countryid
LEFT JOIN resellers r 
    ON r.parentid = 7 
WHERE 
    rl.resellerid = 7 
    OR rl.resellerid = r.resellerid
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should provide some records in your table for us. And then show what is your expected output.

Comment: Working as intended. Your resellerid column is distinct when the countryname is otherwise duplicated. What are the results you actually want to have?

Comment: The second screenshot above would be what i'm looking for.

Comment: Ok, great. Now, when de-duping the countries, how do you decide which resellerid should be the one that is displayed? The resellerid is what is making your records unique, so you have to decide what value "wins" and what value "loses". And if it doesn't matter which resellerid value "wins", then why bother even selecting it?

Answer (score 6):

`DISTINCT` relates to all the columns specified, so if you have e.g. 2 records with the same `countryid` but different `resellerid`, both will show.

Comment: You need to work out which column has different values. Then you need to decide which value you want to keep. If you don't care the quickest solution is to use `MAX` on it. Post some sample data and we can help further